# "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter" php api

Tags: php, api, function, curl

Well, I'm new working with APIs and I have a problem

This is a example of working code, it shows all categories of a web

```
function list_categories(){

    $c = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->xmlHeader);


    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiUrl . "/api/Categories/Get"); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET'); 
    $contentResult = curl_exec($c); 
    curl_close($c); 
        echo $contentResult;    
}
```

And this is when i try to take a single product

```
function get_product($cod_prod){
            $c = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->xmlHeader);

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiUrl . "/api/Product/Get/$cod_prod"); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET'); 
    $contentResult = curl_exec($c);

    curl_close($c); 

    echo $contentResult;
}
```

With the second code I get this error:

**The request is invalid.The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'Secom.Net.WebApi.Models.ProductView Get(Int32)' in 'Secom.Net.WebApi.Controllers.ProductController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.**

All functions that have a variable give the same error, so I think something is wrong with that, it gives the same mistake outside the function...

I don't know what to do... anyone knows what's wrong with the code?

---

i tried with

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Id=$Id");
```

but "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'"

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like you're meant to be specifying an ID variable in your request, usually as part of the URL, and that this is not happening.

Find a way to add the relevant ID and hopefully you'll stop getting that error.

edit:  I think I've found the problem in your code.  You've got your quotes in the wrong place.

Change

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiUrl . "/api/Product/Get/$cod_prod");
```

To

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiUrl . "/api/Product/Get/" . $cod_prod);
```

Comment: I tried /api/Product/Get?id=$cod_prod but it shows the same mistake, maybe i'm missing something

Comment: @user3047498 If all else fails, try typing in the URL you want directly into a browser and make sure you get a response.  It's probably just a numeric id like /api/Product/Get/1  Also, it may be case sensitive, so make sure the capitals for Product and Get are required